# php exception not raised of fatal error,such as "class not exist"

Tags: php

I suppose that the exception system of PHP will catch all. but it doesn't.

```
try{ 
    $obj = new Asdfasdfasdf()
} catch(Exception $e){
    trace(...something...)
}
```

But it doesn't catch this kind of error, and I have searched php document, which didn't say which kind of exception/error is catch-able in try,catch clause.

So, how can I know that which kind of exception/error will be catched by my catch clause ?

P.S.

I finnally understand the 'error' from php engine is not the 'exception' from use land code. If you want use exception to handle engine 'error', you should manually wrap all 'error' in exception.

Comment: A fatal error is not an exception, exceptions are exceptions.... I suggest you start by reading about [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php)

Comment: fatal errors cannot be caught. they don't throw anything. if you want to "catch" this sort of thing, you have to register an error handler/shutdown script.

Comment: @MarkBaker have read the doc, please tell me, in which line, the doc says that exception cannot catch error, and which kind of error cannot be catched by exception

Comment: @MarkBaker I come from c++, and all error in c++ can be handle in exception

Comment: A catch can only catch exceptions, and an error !== an exception.... there are ways of converting many errors to exceptions, but fatal means fatal and terminates the script

Comment: The first relevant part of the docs pages is: `Internal PHP functions mainly use Error reporting, only modern Object oriented extensions use exceptions. However, errors can be simply translated to exceptions with ErrorException. `

Comment: And the relevant link to [ErrorException](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) with an example of how to convert errors to exceptions

Comment: @MarkBaker I finnally understand that ALL ERROR(from  E_ERROR   to  E_USER_DEPRECATED ) will not be catched by exception handler if you do not manually wrap the error in exception format, is it?

Comment: @MarkBaker really helps me, thank u !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to throw an Exception in the event that a class does not exist it, you could use [`class_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php).

A naive example might look something like:

```
function createClass($class)
{
    if (!class_exists($class)) {
        throw new Exception(
            sprintf('Class %s does not exist', $class)
        );
    }

    return new $class;
}

try {
    $asdfasdfasdf = createClass('Asdfasdfasdf');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

From my experience, most PHP frameworks throw some sort of exception when a class is not found - for example, Symfony2 throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. That said, I don't know if you can 'catch' that, it's probably really just a development aid.

PHP 7 has just been released and from what I understand from the spec, you will be able to catch a `fatal error` as an `EngineException`. I don't know if it would work for your example; I haven't tested it because I have not installed PHP 7 stable yet. I tried your example with an alpha release of PHP 7 on an online REPL, and it appears that it does not work.

However for completeness, here's an example from the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7):

```
function call_method($obj) {
    $obj->method();
}

try {
    call_method(null); // oops!
} catch (EngineException $e) {
    echo "Exception: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
}

// Exception: Call to a member function method() on a non-object
```

In any case, as noted by @MarkBaker and @MarcB in the question's comments, you cannot "catch" a `fatal error` in previous versions of PHP.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank u! it really help me understand that the error and exception are two different system in PHP, if you want catch "error", you have to manually  wrap "error" in a exception

Comment: No problem @lovespring :)